# Python selenium: How to save a value of a div (with xpath)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have a question about selenium with Python
I want to create a programm that save the message of the newest E-mail on trash-mail.com
But i can't locate the element that saved the Message.
My programm looks now like this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time, random, sys
zaehler = 0
Bots = 20
messagenumber = 1


def FindNewestMail():
    global messagenumber
    global newestMessage
    while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_id("refresh-inbox")
            break

        except:
            driver.refresh()
    while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_class_name("message-from")
            print("A E-mail is existing")
            break
        except:
            driver.find_element_by_id("refresh-inbox").click()
    while True:
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_id(f"message-from-{messagenumber}").click()
            break
        except:
            messagenumber += 1
    while True:
        try:
            message =     driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]').get_attribute("value")
            print(type(message))
            return message
        except Exception as error:
            print("Error Message is: \n" + str(error))
            driver.close()
            sys.exit()


while zaehler < Bots:
    E_Mail = "test"+str(zaehler)
    E_Mail = str(E_Mail)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.trash-mail.com/posteingang/")
    InputEmail = driver.find_element_by_id("inputEmail")
    InputEmail.send_keys(E_Mail)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(6))
    driver.find_element_by_id("fetch-mails").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    print(f"The message of the newest E-mail is: \n\"{str(FindNewestMail())}\"")
    break
```

But i don't know how to save to value of the div that saved the Message.
If you want to read teh source-code of the site go on https://www.trash-mail.com/posteingang/ and enter a username you like. 
Thanks a lot for your help.
Kcinay055679

Comment: that error is not the only thing in this code. why you had to use that while True loops?
i tested your code and it stucks a loop even before website opened

Comment: I'm sorry i don't posted the full code, now i did it.